# Python - How is it possible to get SSL Error (Max retries exceeded with url) at first request?

Tags: python, ssl, request, python-requests, ssl-certificate

Here's my code :

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.vidal.fr/rest/api/products?app_id=MY_ID&app_key=MY_KEY&q=doliprane"

response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

And this is the error I get:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_classes.py", line 6, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
  File "/Users/christou/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/christou/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/christou/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/christou/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/christou/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.vidal.fr', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/products?app_id=MY_ID&app_key=MY_KEY&q=doliprane (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)'),))
```

My code is pretty simple, and after some research I understand the problem is probably coming from an wrong certificate (although the 'verify=False' doesn't help) or maybe old versions (Python or SSL)...

Don't let the error message mislead you, this is the very first request I made to this API. At this point can't exceed any maximum number of requests. When I copy/paste the URL in my browser it works perfectly.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

> I understand the problem is probably coming from an wrong certificate ...

No. Server certificate validation is done locally and does not result in the shown error.

> ... or maybe old versions (Python or SSL)

More likely. Nothing is known about your versions of Python (except that it is 2.7.whatever) and openssl, but this error for example happens if your openssl does not support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 since TLS 1.0 is disabled on the server. For example MacOS came for years with a very old version of openssl which caused such errors.

It might also a problem with some firewall blocking the connections during the TLS handshake. Hard to tell. But you might try to access the site from the same machine with a different client to narrow down the problem.